# How to send data to command line after calling .sh file?

Tags: sh

I want to install Anaconda through EasyBuild. EasyBuild is a software to manage software installation on clusters. Anaconda can be installed with `sh Anaconda.sh`.
However, after running I have to accept the License agreement and give the installation location on the command line by entering `<Enter>`, `yes <Enter>`, `path/where/to/install/ <Enter>`.

Because this has to be installed automatically I want to do the accepting of terms and giving the install location in one line. I tried to do it like this:

```
sh Anaconda.sh  < <(echo) >/dev/null < <(echo yes) >/dev/null \
    < <(echo /apps/software/Anaconda/1.8.0-Linux-x86_64/) > test.txt
```

From the test.txt I can read that the first echo works as `<Enter>`, but I can't figure out how to accept the License agreement, as it sees it now as not sending yes:

```
Do you approve the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>> The license agreement wasn't approved, aborting installation.
```

How can I send the yes correctly to the script input?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Sorry, I missed the part about having to enter more then one thing. You can take a look at writing expect scripts. thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples. You may need to install it however.

You could try piping with the following command: `yes yes | sh Anaconda.sh`.  Read the man pages for more information `man yes`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about having to enter more then one thing.  You can take a look at writing expect scripts.  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/.  You may need to install it however.

Comment: Can you edit expect into your answer? I quickly looked and I think that that will do what I want, so I can accept it after testing. Although if possible I would like to do it without the expect script.

Comment: Great, I hope it works out for you.  I've updated my original answer with information regarding expect scripts.

Comment: doesn't do exactly what I want so I'll keep the question open for now.

Answer (score 2):

Expect is a great way to go and probably the most error proof way. If you know all the questions I think you could do this by just writing a file with the answers in the correct order, one per line and piping it in.

That install script is huge so as long as you can verify you know all the questions you could give this a try.

In my simple tests it works.

I have a test script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo -n "Do you accept " 
read ANS 
echo $ANS 
echo -n "Install path: " 
read ANS
echo $ANS
```

and an answers file that looks like this:

```
Y
/usr
```

Running it like so works... perhaps it will work for your monster install file as well.

```
cat answers | ./test.sh 
Do you accept Y
Install path: /usr
```

If that doesn't work then the script is likely flushing and you will have to use expect or pexpect.

Good luck!

Actually, I downloaded and looked at the anaconda install script.   Looks like it takes command line arguments.

```
/bin/bash Anaconda-2.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -h 
usage: Anaconda-2.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh [options]

Installs Anaconda 2.2.0

-b           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
             it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
-f           no error if install prefix already exists
-h           print this help message and exit
-p PREFIX    install prefix, defaults to /home/cody.stevens/anaconda
```

Use the -b and -p options...
so use it like so:

```
/bin/bash Anaconda-2.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /usr
```

Also of note.. that script explicitly says not to run with  '.'  or 'sh' but 'bash' so they must have some dependency on a feature of bash.

-- 
Cody